# How can I add horizontal space within a paragraph to move the remainder of the line to some margin?

Tags: spacing, width, white-space

I am trying to find a Latex command that can be used within a paragraph to create whitespace until some specified distance from the left margin is reached, and then the text resumes. It should do nothing if the specified distance is already reached.

It should stay left-aligned and any following line should begin at the normal margin - these are the parts I can't manage.

So for example if this horizontal space was created after each instance of the word 'part':

```
A first part               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisc-
ing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliq-
ua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

A longer first part        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisc-
ing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliq-
ua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

A much much much much much longer first part Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation...

Part                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisc-
ing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliq-
ua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a paragraph header that takes up a minimum space.

You need to get the text of your paragraph header, compare it to a wanted length, and iff the header is shorter, skip the remaining space. So you need a conditional. Using "etoolbox", something like the following might do what you want:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\myheadlength}
\newlength{\requestedheadspace}
\newlength{\addedheadspace}
\setlength{\requestedheadspace}{.4\textwidth}% <--adjust to taste

\newcommand{\parstart}[1]{%
    \settowidth{\myheadlength}{#1}%
    \setlength{\addedheadspace}{\requestedheadspace}
%    %compare to required width
    \ifdimless{\myheadlength}{\requestedheadspace}{% then
        \addtolength{\addedheadspace}{-\myheadlength}%
        #1\hspace{\addedheadspace}%
    }%
    {%else just print the header
    #1%
    }%
}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\raggedright
\begin{document}

\parstart{Dummy}\lipsum[1]

\parstart{Less short dummy}\lipsum[1]

\parstart{And a very very long dummy to go beyond the requested space} Some text \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

(tested with PdfLatex and LuaLatex)

Comment: That works exactly as I hoped, thanks. The only thing I notice is that if the header is multiple lines long, it is not right justified. e.g., when I put the above text in columns 'requested' gets put on a new line with white space at the right of the previous line (when usually it would abut the right margin by breaking it across line into re-quested or request-ed).

Comment: Update: if I remove '\raggedright' it fixes this. Will this break some other functionality that needs \raggedright which I've overlooked?

Comment: Not as far as I know, I put in the `\raggedright` to make sure the spacing after the header text was correct

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this using an itemize style environment.
I don't know whether the use of an environment is desirable in your situation, but it may be worth considering.

Below, I'm using the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to create the `parswithheads` environment (to be replaced by a more inspiring name) and tweak its indentation (see the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/show.php?pkg=enumitem) for more info).

```
\documentclass{article}

%% To match your desired output:
%% (sets parindent to 0pt and parskip to .5\baselineskip plus 2pt)
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{parswithheads}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[parswithheads]{
  align=left, %% alignment of labels
  listparindent=\parindent, %% same indentation as in normal text
  parsep=\parskip, %% same parskip as in normal text
  topsep=0pt, %% vertical space above and below list
  partopsep=0pt, %% extra vertical space above and below if separate paragraph
  itemsep=0pt, %% no extra space between items
  font=\normalfont\bfseries, %% font used for labels, you may want to remove \bfseries
  leftmargin=0pt, %% don't indent the entire paragraph
  itemindent=4cm, %% how much to indent the first line by (at least)
  labelsep=.5em, %% space between label and text
  labelindent=0pt, %% label starts at the left margin
  labelwidth=! %% calculated from other values
}
\begin{document}

\framebox[4cm]{$\longleftarrow$\hfill 4cm\hfill$\longrightarrow$}

\begin{parswithheads}
\item[A first part]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\ldots
\item[A longer first part]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\ldots
\item[A much much much much much longer first part]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\ldots
\item[Part]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\ldots
\end{parswithheads}

\end{document}
```

Below is an overview of the lengths involved. I'm setting `leftmargin` and `labelindent` to `0pt`, `itemindent` to `4cm` and `labelsep` to `.5em` (the maximum amount a normal space can be stretched to by default iirc). I added `labelwidth=!` so that the amount of space reserved for the label is calculated from the other lengths (so it'll be `4cm-.5em` in this case). If the actual label is wider than this length it will cause the item to be indented further (as desired).

[image]

Anyway, here is the result:

[image]

---

**Edit:** If you consider loading `enumitem` just for this a bit excessive, which I can imagine, then the following should also work. The result is (as far as I can tell) indistinguishable.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% To match your desired output:
%% (sets parindent to 0pt and parskip to .5\baselineskip plus 2pt)
\usepackage{parskip}

\newlength{\partitlewidth}
\setlength{\partitlewidth}{4cm}
\newcommand*\partitle[1]{%
  \begingroup %% To limit the scope of box 0
    \savebox0{\textbf{#1}\hspace{.5em}}% %% Save the title in a box, with some added space
    \ifdim\wd0<\partitlewidth\wd0=\partitlewidth\fi %% Set width of box 0 to \partitlewidth if it is shorter
    \usebox0% %% Print the box
  \endgroup
  \ignorespaces %% Ignore any ensuing following spaces
}

\begin{document}

\framebox[4cm]{$\longleftarrow$\hfill 4cm\hfill$\longrightarrow$}

\partitle{A first part}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\ldots

\partitle{A longer first part}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\ldots

\partitle{A much much much much much longer first part}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\ldots

\partitle{Part}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris\ldots

\end{document}
```

The macro `\partitle` puts its argument in a "box" (along with a space) and sets the width of this box to `\partitlewidth` if it is shorter before printing the box. Any spaces following the macro are ignored. (This is necessary because spaces are can be stretched/shrunk, which would otherwise alter the indentation.)